# How Can I Run These 3 SQL Queries

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I've got the following tables set up in my DB:

```
student (sid, sname, gender, gpa)
department (dname, numphds)
professor (pname, dname)
course (cno, cname, dname)
major (dname, sid)
enroll (sid, grade, dname, cno)
```

I'm trying to solve these three problems, which I cannot figure out:

1. Find the names of the departments such that every student who
   is majoring in that department does not take the Compiler Construction course.
2. A department is called ’under performing’ if there are one or more
   students who are majoring in that department and have GPA <
   1.5. Find the names of all under performing departments and the
   average GPA of the students who are majoring in that department.
3. Find the name(s) and major(s) of students who are taking the
   Thermodynamics course (note BOTH cno=310 and dname="Chemical Engineering" signify a Thermodynamics course).

For #3, I've got the following so far:

```
query6 = ''' SELECT sname, major.dname
            FROM student
            JOIN major ON student.sid = major.sid
            JOIN enroll ON enroll.sid = student.sid
            JOIN course ON course.cno = enroll.cno
            WHERE cname = "Thermodynamics"
            AND course.dname = "Chemical Engineering"
'''
```

Comment: Please can you explain the relation between the tables and provide some sample data. A DBfiddle would be appreciated.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about how SQL works so this is a direction for a query.

for #1:

```
SELECT dname FROM department WHERE dname NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT dname FROM enroll WHERE cno = (
        SELECT cno FROM course WHERE cname = 'Compiler Construction course'
    )
)
```

for #2: I will show you how to get the dnames but you will have to get the average by yourself maybe by making a view or something like that.

```
SELECT dname FROM department WHERE dname NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT dname FROM enroll WHERE sid NOT IN(
        SELECT sid FROM student WHERE gpa < 1.5
    )
)
```

for #3 I think you forgot a primary key for major as students who major twice at the same department will have the same sid and the same dname.

Comment: I was able to use #1 and #2 to write my own query that worked, your direction helped thanks.